# Setting cookies before a redirect in Phoenix Framework Elixir

Tags: cookies, elixir, phoenix-framework

I am noticing that my cookies are not being set when I perform put_resp_cookie() before a redirect.

```
conn
|> put_resp_cookie("shop", shop)

if (some_condition) do:
  redirect conn, to: "/foo/bar"
```

In my controller function for /foo/bar, the cookie is not set. Is there a way to set the cookie?

Comment: Did you forget to reassign `conn` after setting the cookie? `conn = conn |> put_resp_cookie(..)`?

Comment: I thought the syntax I used would do that, as per this blog post: https://www.amberbit.com/elixir-cocktails/phoenix/reading-and-writing-cookies-in-phoenix-with-plug/

Comment: Nope, a pipe doesn't reassign. The reason that code works is because it returns the new `conn` directly while you are doing an `if` after the pipe.

Comment: @Dogbert Feel free to add an answer and I will accept it. That worked.

Answer (score 3):

It appears you did not reassign `conn`.  You simply piped conn into `put_resp_cookie/2` but didn't capture the value.  You probably intended to do something like this instead

```
conn = conn |> put_resp_cookie("shop", shop)
```